# Texlive Utility fails, apparently due to xz missing,

Tags: mac, tlmgr, update, texlive-2023

Texlive Utility fails and it looks like the failure is related to `xz` not being available.

However I have `/usr/local/xz` installed and checked that it runs in sh.

I am using a McBook late 2009 (macbook6,1) running Sonoma 14.1.1 base on Opencore Legacy Patcher 1.2.1.
Here are the log lines complaining about xz.
The complete log is also included.

```
2023-11-18 11:55:42 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[1485] + echo './runme.sh: no xz.[x86_64-darwinlegacy][.exe] binary for /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy in /var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/selfgz148632661/installer/xz.'
2023-11-18 11:55:42 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][915]  kqueue noted that pid 1486 exited (/var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.HhD30y/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11 -- --debug)
2023-11-18 11:55:42 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[1485] ./runme.sh: no xz.[x86_64-darwinlegacy][.exe] binary for /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy in /var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/selfgz148632661/installer/xz.
2023-11-18 11:55:42 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[1485] + exit 1
2023-11-18 11:55:42 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[1485]  child process pid = 1486 exited
2023-11-18 11:55:43 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[1485]  exit status of pid = 1486 was 1
2023-11-18 11:55:43 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][915]  exit status of pid = 1485 was 1
2023-11-18 11:55:43 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][915]  kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 1485) exited with status 1
```

Complete log:

```
2023-11-18 12:53:21 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][915]    Invoking privileged task via AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges
2023-11-18 12:53:21 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  dropped privileges to user nobody
2023-11-18 12:53:22 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment _handleLocationOperationFinished:][915]   Finished setting command line server location:
    location = https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
2023-11-18 12:53:22 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setWrapperPID:][915]  tlu_ipctask checking in:  tlu_ipctask pid = 3286
2023-11-18 12:53:23 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setUnderlyingPID:][915]   tlu_ipctask checking in: pid = 3287 (/var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.betlwn/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11 -- --debug)
2023-11-18 12:53:23 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  tlu_ipctask: child HOME = '/var/root'
2023-11-18 12:53:23 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  tlu_ipctask: current HOME = '/var/empty'
2023-11-18 12:53:23 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  Verifying archive integrity... All good.
2023-11-18 12:53:24 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] 0%    44%    88%  100%  /var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.betlwn/update-tlmgr-latest.sh: line 204: /dev/tty: Device not configured
2023-11-18 12:53:24 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater
2023-11-18 12:53:24 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  ./runme.sh: updating in /usr/local/texlive/2023...
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  ./runme.sh: tlmgr version says this is TeX Live 2023,
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  ./runme.sh: and this updater script created: Thu Nov 16 02:12:22 CET 2023.
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  ./runme.sh: proceeding with tlmgr update.
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + test x = x--upgrade
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + echo './runme.sh: proceeding with tlmgr update.'
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + mv ./master/bin .
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + mkdir ./installer
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/tar.exe ./installer
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/xz ./installer
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/wget ./installer
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/lz4 ./installer
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + cd master
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + tar cf - LICENSE.CTAN LICENSE.TL README README.usergroups index.html readme-html.dir readme-txt.dir release-texlive.txt texmf-dist tlpkg
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + cd /usr/local/texlive/2023
2023-11-18 12:53:26 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + tar xf -
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + t_instdir=/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + t_xzdir=/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/xz
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + t_wgetdir=/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/wget
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/xz /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/wget
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + src_tlpobj=master/tlpkg/tlpobj
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + tlpobjs=master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + test -n 1
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] pwd
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] ++ pwd
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + : 'here (/var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/selfgz328717045):'
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + ls
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] bin
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] installer
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] master
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] runme.sh
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + : installer:
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + ls installer
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] lz4
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] tar.exe
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] wget
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] xz
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + : installer/wget:
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + ls installer/wget
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + : installer/xz:
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + ls installer/xz
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + : ROOT/bin=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin:
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + ls /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] x86_64-darwinlegacy
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + for a in '"$ROOT"/bin/*'
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + test -d /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] basename "$a"
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] ++ basename /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + b=x86_64-darwinlegacy
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + test x86_64-darwinlegacy = man
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + echo './runme.sh: updating /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy ...'
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + tlpobjs='master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-darwinlegacy.tlpobj'
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  ./runme.sh: updating /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy ...
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + cd bin
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + tar cf - x86_64-darwinlegacy
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + cd /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + tar xf -
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + test -r installer/xz/xz.x86_64-darwinlegacy
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + test -r installer/xz/xz.x86_64-darwinlegacy.exe
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + echo x86_64-darwinlegacy
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + egrep 'win32|windows'
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] pwd
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] ++ pwd
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + echo './runme.sh: no xz.[x86_64-darwinlegacy][.exe] binary for /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy in /var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/selfgz328717045/installer/xz.'
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] ./runme.sh: no xz.[x86_64-darwinlegacy][.exe] binary for /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy in /var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/selfgz328717045/installer/xz.
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3286] + exit 1
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][915]  kqueue noted that pid 3287 exited (/var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.betlwn/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11 -- --debug)
2023-11-18 12:53:27 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  child process pid = 3287 exited
2023-11-18 12:53:28 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3286]  exit status of pid = 3287 was 1
2023-11-18 12:53:28 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][915]  exit status of pid = 3286 was 1
2023-11-18 12:53:28 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][915]  kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 3286) exited with status 1
2023-11-18 12:53:28 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation main][915]   Removed temp directory "/var/folders/32/p5g_8z417w7chjzxml4dv6sw0000gr/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.betlwn"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many users, including me, had this same problem. Running `sudo tlmgr update --self` in a Terminal fixes the problem. Hat tip to Joseph Wright and Alan Munn for the fix.

Comment: Does that command permanently fix the issue?

Comment: It seems to have as far as I can tell. I have not had any problems updating since.

Comment: I was updating to MacTeX2023 and decided to install with brew.  Then I was unable to install infrastructure updates due to a (reasonable) security limitation on the brew package, so I uninstalled via brew. Apparently this broke the database file for TexLive.  I then ran 'brew clean' which got rid of some files that was confusing tlmgr (tlpdb file still pointed into the Cask directory). Then I had to reset my home repository via tlmgr. THEN the above answer solved the remaining issue. Now it's back to running fine.  In any event, the brew version doesn't work for me and it caused a headache.

Comment: @DavidSnyder I think most of the experts would say to avoid using Homebrew to install TeX Live. I know it puts things in different home locations on M1 Macs vs. Intel Macs and that may also affect TeX Live. Note that I've always just used Mac TeX so I may be wrong. I do use Homebrew for several other much smaller things (e.g. git, bash, etc.).

Comment: @murray The issue is currently under investigation, and will likely be fixed going forward, so that users won't encounter it. But this command doesn't just does the updating in a slightly different way from what TL Utility is doing, so it's not directly fixing the problem. It will always work, but going forward, TL Utility should also continue to work as it always has.

Comment: @DavidSnyder There is really no upside to intstalling MacTeX using `homebrew`, and as you've found, it can also give you problems. Like LaTeXereXeTaL I use `homebrew` for various things, but definitely not for MacTeX.

Comment: TeX Live Utility maintainer here: this was a packaging problem that the TeX Live team fixed yesterday, so should not occur again. This question would be better asked in the TeX Live Utility email list or the github bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you @AdamMaxwell.

Answer (score 4):

You can now work around this in TeX Live Utility by holding down the **Option** key and choosing **Install TeX Live Manager From Critical Repository** in the **Actions** menu.

This feature allows TeX Live Utility users to beta test new versions of `tlmgr` by installing `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` from https://tug.org/texlive/tlcritical/. The fixed script should be pushed out tonight (20 November), so will work its way to the mirrors soon.

Thanks to Bruno Voisin for an amazing job of finding the root cause [summarized here](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2023-November/049715.html) and to Karl Berry for actually implementing the fixes. This was a pretty obscure problem.

Comment: Thank you for your great work!