Latex on two different Macs with same MacTex2024 install fails on one
I run TexShop (latest) on two different Macs with different results. The MacTex2024 installations should be identical but aren't. Packages are up to date in both cases.
I have installed MacTex2024 in early 2024 on an MacBook6,1 running OSX 15.1 (open core legacy patcher).
Running TexShop gives
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MyPaper.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(./journal.cls

etc etc the run finishes correctly.
I notice "LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1".
The 2023 distribution is not present in /usr/local/texlive, as I deleted it.
Then, I just installed MacTex2024 on an iMac13,2 running Catalina.
Running TexShop (latest) on the same file in the same (iCloud) directory as before gives
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MyPaper.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>

! Latex Error: File 'journal.cls' not found.

No document is produced, obviously.
Note the absence of the path '.'.
The file 'journal.cls' is in the directory.
How can I make this work?
Besides this error I notice two differences

LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>

How come the later, iMac, install is different?
Is this due to the osx difference?
If so, I would expect the iMac install to have the earlier versions.
I did not want to disclose the journal nor the name of my paper, hence the generic filenames.

the first one is from an original not-updated texlive 2024, before the June LaTeX release so using the november 2023 latex. the second one says that journal.cls is not in the current directory (or more exactly, can not be read, file permissions could make it be unreadable)

I would first check that pdflatex is working, don;t use the texshop frontdend to debug, juts use the terminal cd to the directory with the paper and type pdflatex MyPaper  do you get the same error? If that works, then it is your editor config not the tex installation that is at fault

when you install MacTeX, it downloads the current version of TeX Live. There is one edition of TL per year, but TeX Live gets updated continually for much of the year. During that time, a network install gets whatever is current. Then TL is 'frozen' in preparation for the new edition. for a while, they just work on that and don't update the current version again. once the new edition is released, it gets updated in its turn.

unless you copy one install to the other or install during the annual 'freeze' or download everything as a source for both installs, the installs may differ even if the hardware and software is the same and they are installed at the same time because they may use different mirrors and one may be more up-to-date than the other.

Oops. The first question, why can't pidflatex see the class file has a trivial answer, fortunately. I overlooked the little cloud symbol that I needed to click on in order to actually download the file! I haven't seen that in a year or so since I moved to later osx's with OCLP. (OCLP spectacularly failed a few days ago so I have returned to Catalina).

The question remains why the two installs are so different. They are both up to date and were both installed after March 13, the release date.

When you say "they are both up to date" have you run TeX Live Utility (or tlmgr from the command line) to update both systems? You always need to do that after installing a new MacTeX. Or perhaps you ran the update on one machine and not the  other?

Furthemore, if iCloud is like other cloud systems (I only use it to back up my phone, so I don't know) it stores files in the cloud and not locally. This means that sometimes files will not be found by TeX programs, since the system is designed with GUI apps in mind, so opening/double clicking on a file downloads it. This could be the source of your file not found error for journal.cls. So try setting the folder to "Always available on this computer" or equivalent.

Oops, guilty as charged. My apologies. I now realise that I gave up on updating on the macbook months ago. I still can’t update even after a clean install.

I did a clean install, I ran the tlmgr self update after I reinstalled tlmgr from the critical repository to no avail.
Still the same complaint about xz, which is installed and up to date.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701619/texlive-utility-fails-apparently-due-to-xz-missing
